# Change option menu background dynamically

Tags: android, menu, background

I have a "Cart" item in a menu option, and I'd like to display the number of products in the cart, as shown below.

[image]

To achieve this I want to create several images with numbers from 1 to 9 and 9+ and set the correct image as the background of the corresponding menu option item when opening the menu.

How can I do this, i.e. how can I change the background of a menu option item dynamically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` menu method. It is called each time user clicks `Menu` button.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Let's find id of resource for drawable with required count
    // assuming you have cartIcon1.png, cartIcon2.png etc
    // in your `drawable` folder
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("cartIcon" + numberOfElementsInCart, "drawable", getPackageName()); 

    if (resId != 0)
        menu.findItem(R.id.cart).setIcon(resId);
    // If resource was not found, set default icon
    else 
        menu.findItem(R.id.cart).setIcon(R.drawable.defaultCart);

    return true;
}
```

Overriding background is much harder, and I believe it's more convinient to have icons with cart and number, since you already have .png for each number

Answer (score 0):

Below is a horrible, horrible hack to change the background image of menus - note that it'll change all the menu item backgrounds. There is probably an easier way to do this now, but this was the only way I found a year or so ago.

Setting the icon of the menu item is a lot easier, and can be done in onPrepareOptionsMenu

```
// Hack to make the menu item selector blue
    protected void setMenuBackground(final int id)
    {
        if(getLayoutInflater().getFactory() != null)
            return;
        getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory()
        {
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
            {
                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
                        final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);
                        //What?
                        //Well the Android system is going to set the background after this is method is done
                        //so we run it later to override the override. Simples?
                        new Handler().post(new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                view.setBackgroundResource(id);
                            }
                        });
                        return view;
                    }
                    catch(InflateException e)
                    {
                    }
                    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
                    {

                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
```