# How to change navigation drawer menu background?

Tags: android

How to change menu background of android Navigation Drawer?
    I tried many ways on stackoverflow but failed.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167531/change-option-menu-background-dynamically
It did not work.

activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

          <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_white_24dp"
            android:title="@string/menu_home"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/homedr"
            />
</menu>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/cardview_dark_background</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/cardview_dark_background</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/cardview_dark_background</item>



    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? Do you want to set the background of a single item? Dynamically?

Comment: Yes I want to set single item's background with drawable.

Comment: Only 1 item ? or the selected item?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in the NavigationView

```
android:background="@color/color_navigation_view_background"
```

or with Java

mNavigationView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

I'm assuming you're using AndroidX so here's it.

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    android:background="@color/color_navigation_view_background"
    app:itemIconTint="?colorAccent"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu">
  </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

Comment: In your activity_main.xml most probably depending how you named your Activity. But it's your default activity layout.